Multiple 1D interpolation in 2D array without loop
I have an np array with ndim = 2. I need to sample interpolated values along one dimension, and I would like to do it as efficiently as possible.
I came up with this solution:
for i in range(my_array.shape[0]):
    my_interp_array[i, :] = np.interp(sample_y , np.arange(array_size_y), my_array[i,:])

... with sample_y being some non-equidistant sampling vector. Although this gives the desired result, this is probably a very inefficient solution.
I also tried scipy.interpolate.interp1d, as it was suggested by others, like this:
y = np.arange(array_size_y)  # equidistant sampling vector
intf = interp1d(y, my_array)  # interpolation function
my_interp_array = intf(np.tile(sample_y, (len(y), 1)))

... but this actually takes >3000x longer than the first idea with the for loop, which confuses me.
Has someone an idea how to improve this and why the scipy interpolation is so much slower for me?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I made a reproducible example as some asked for this. Following code gives me results that show that scipy.interpolate.interp1d is 800-1000 times slower than the method with the for loop.
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

size_x, size_y = 512, 512

# make dummy arrays
my_array = np.random.rand(size_x, size_y)
my_interp_array = np.zeros_like(my_array)

# make indices
iy = np.arange(size_y)  # "normal" indices
sample_y = iy + (iy ** 2 / np.max(iy ** 2))  # indices from where to get the values
sample_y[-1] = sample_y[-2]  # avoid index out of range error

# for loop method
start1 = time.time()
for i in range(size_y):
    my_interp_array[i, :] = np.interp(sample_y, iy, my_array[i, :])
end1 = time.time()

# scipy interp1d method
start2 = time.time()
intf = interp1d(np.arange(size_y), my_array)
my_interp_array = intf(np.tile(sample_y, (size_y, 1)))
end2 = time.time()

# print times
print(f"interp1d is {(end2 - start2) / (end1 - start1)} times slower than the for loop")

This is less bad than factor 3000, but the difference is still remarkable in my opinion.

AFAIK scipy.interpolate.interp1d is a convenient function but not efficient and it does thinks similar to a loop you do performance-wise (possibly with additional overhead since AFAIK it is more flexible -- like non-linear interpolations). Actually, the documentation states: "This class is considered legacy and will no longer receive updates. This could also mean it will be removed in future SciPy versions". Thus, the first solution is actually better.

You can move away np.arange(array_size_y) from the loop since it seems to be constant and recomputed every time.

Be aware that generic interpolations tend to be expensive to compute, especially when the array domain is large. If your arrays are large, using Numba with multiple threads can help. If the domain is large, then the computation will be memory-bound anyway (by the memory latency or throughput due to the cache-line size overhead).

In the case where interp1d is asked to produce a linear interpolation of a 2-dimensional array, it uses the following code: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.14.0/scipy/interpolate/_interpolate.py#L457-L484 This code is vectorized, so it may be faster than the Python loop in that respect, but it also may have worse cache efficiency, due to multiple large intermediate arrays. However, I would be surprised if that resulted in a 3000x difference. Seconding the reproducible example.

Thank you for your responses. @jared I posted an example in the edit. What do you think?

@Nick Odell That might be an explanation for this, as the arrays I use are rather largen (~512x512).

You should use scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline as follows: f = make_interp_spline(iy, my_array, k=1, axis=1) (k=1 means linear interpolation and you want axis=1 to match the interpolation you're doing in the looping version) and then interpolate as my_interp_array = f(sample_y). And be careful, in your current code, the two my_interp_arrays are not equal.

@jared Done ;) . By the way, interp1d performs a linear interpolation, while scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline is a spline-based interpolation (computationally significantly more expensive, though overheads might not be the same, and not equivalent).

Thank you for your reply. scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline is actually significantly faster than interp1d, but still slower than the for loop. It appears that the time complexity in the scipy methods increases exponentially with the array sizes, while the for loop's increases linearly (at least along one axis).
I'll stick to the loop for now, I think.

@JérômeRichard With k=1 they produce the same results. I verified that with np.allclose.

You can use scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline with k=1 (for linear interpolation) and axis=1 (to match the same axis of interpolation as the looping code).
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

f = make_interp_spline(iy, my_array, k=1, axis=1)
my_interp_array = f(sample_y)

Time comparison:
def original(iy, my_array, sample_y):
    my_interp_array = np.zeros_like(my_array)
    for i in range(size_y):
        my_interp_array[i, :] = np.interp(sample_y, iy, my_array[i, :])
    return my_interp_array

def mine(iy, my_array, sample_y):
    f = make_interp_spline(iy, my_array, k=1, axis=1)
    my_interp_array = f(sample_y)
    return my_interp_array

%timeit original(iy, my_array, sample_y)
3.38 ms ± 82.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit mine(iy, my_array, sample_y)
1.64 ms ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

So, this approach results in a little more than a 2x speed up.

I get a 2.3x speed up on my machine. Interestingly, 40% of the time is spent in make_interp_spline so I guess there it is not optimal. Each Numpy function takes 9 µs on my machine which so small that Numpy overheads becomes significant.

I get different (wrong?) results with iy = np.sort(np.random.rand(512)*512). Is this normal?

@JérômeRichard Hmm, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't (depending on what iy comes out to). I'm not sure why that is.

Was able to reproduce your results. Thanks!
